# $(window).on('load') doesn't work with Mozilla Firexfox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a loading screen for a website which i have designed and it works great and correct with Chrome but in Firefox it just keep loading as if it doesn't understand the jQuery code.

Here is the code :

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    $('.loading-screen').fadeOut(1000,function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Well Firefox does in fact fire a "load" event and it definitely works. What is the context for your code?

Comment: @Adosi the `.load()` shortcut is deprecated and internally used `on()` anyway

Comment: Have you tried the `DOMContentLoaded` event?

Comment: Something else is causing your problems. No reason that won't work as seen here and tested in firefox http://jsfiddle.net/n290ewmu/1/

Comment: can you check the shared jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n290ewmu/1/ by @charlietfl. if the issue is specific to your browser version then ideally the fiddle should not work in your browser too.

Comment: my Firefox is up-to-date and DOMContentLoaded is just the same as $(document).ready() but my website has many images

Comment: is this error in firefox console related to the problem ?

Source map error: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
Resource URL: file:///../Web%20Design/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
Source Map URL: bootstrap.css.map

Comment: jsfiddle.net/n290ewmu/1 is working with me

Comment: I GOT IT .. The error was because of a missing bootstrap.css.map file i don't know why chrome doesn't have a problem with that but Firefox care too much for that and now it's working !! .. Thanks anyway guys :)

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried `$(document).ready`?:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.loading-screen').fadeOut(1000,function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes and it works with both but i searched and i found that it occurs after the html document loads while "load" occurs when all content loads and my website has a lot of images